# zf2 JSON-RPC server how to return custom error

Tags: zend-framework2, json-rpc

I'm looking for the proper way to return a custom error from a JSON-RPC exposed class.

JSON-RPC has a special format for reporting error conditions. All errors need to provide, minimally, an error message and error code; optionally, they can provide additional data, such as a backtrace.

Error codes are derived from those recommended by the XML-RPC EPI project. Zend\Json\Server appropriately assigns the code based on the error condition. For application exceptions, the code ‘-32000’ is used.

I will use the divide method of the sample code from documentation to explain:

```
<?php
/**
 * Calculator - sample class to expose via JSON-RPC
 */
class Calculator
{
    /**
     * Return sum of two variables
     *
     * @param  int $x
     * @param  int $y
     * @return int
     */
    public function add($x, $y)
    {
        return $x + $y;
    }

    /**
     * Return difference of two variables
     *
     * @param  int $x
     * @param  int $y
     * @return int
     */
    public function subtract($x, $y)
    {
        return $x - $y;
    }

    /**
     * Return product of two variables
     *
     * @param  int $x
     * @param  int $y
     * @return int
     */
    public function multiply($x, $y)
    {
        return $x * $y;
    }

    /**
     * Return the division of two variables
     *
     * @param  int $x
     * @param  int $y
     * @return float
     */
    public function divide($x, $y)
    {
        if ($y == 0) {
            // Say "y must not be zero" in proper JSON-RPC error format
            // e.g. something like {"error":{"code":-32600,"message":"Invalid Request","data":null},"id":null} 
        } else {
            return $x / $y;
        }
    }
}


$server = new Zend\Json\Server\Server();
$server->setClass('Calculator');

if ('GET' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    // Indicate the URL endpoint, and the JSON-RPC version used:
    $server->setTarget('/json-rpc.php')
    ->setEnvelope(Zend\Json\Server\Smd::ENV_JSONRPC_2);

    // Grab the SMD
    $smd = $server->getServiceMap();

    // Return the SMD to the client
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $smd;
    return;
}

$server->handle();
```

p.s. Yes I tried Google search.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I have no experience in using `Zend\Json\Server` whatsoever :)

If you talk about an error response, I can correlate that to the `Server::fault()` method (also [available on Github](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Json/Server/Server.php#L147)). So I assume if `fault()` is called and injected into the respones, it would return the response with error messages according to your referred recommended XML-RPC server standard.

The handler method proxies the actual work to [`_handle()`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Json/Server/Server.php#L482) (linked to the source) where a [try/catch](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Json/Server/Server.php#L539-L543) is encapsuling the dispatching to the (in your case) Calculator class.

The fault is called based on the exception message and exception code. As such I think it's simply throwing an exception and setting the right message/code there:

```
use Zend\Json\Server\Error;

class Calculator
{
    public function divide($x, $y) 
    {
        if (0 === $y) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(
                'Denominator must be a non-zero numerical',
                Error::ERROR_INVALID_PARAMS
            );
        }

        // Rest here
    }

    // Rest here
}
```

PS. I also changed your error code here, as to me, it feels -32602 (invalid params) is more appropriate than -32600 (invalid request.